# Are all Mac Programs built in Objective C?

Tags: c, macos

I know this seems like a simply question, but I'm rather curious.
Are all Mac Programs built in Objective C? Throughout my whole college experience, we have constantly been building throw away programs, ones that we simply run on a linux based command line or in an IDE like Netbeans. To be honest, I'm seriously sick and tired of it. I'm interested in building something real and meaningful, something that perhaps has a GUI or whatnot. Something that would work on any Apple OSX. Can someone give me a push in the right direction, any sources?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not all, but the vast majority. There are also some written in Java (like Netbeans itself), some written in C++ with Qt (like Google Earth), and so on. ObjC is definitely the most common though, and the one the OS's APIs are designed for.

Comment: Some of my Mac apps are written in Delphi :-). But I agree that Objective-C is the most common. Note that Apple also provides Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but most good apps have at least the UI written in Objective-C...

there is a lot of history, in the original OS (classic) everything was written and documented in Pascal, then it migrated with the same API's to C++, then when OSX came along it made the old API's into something called Carbon, the new stuff was cocoa, and there was also a 1:1 Java mapping for most of the objects... also the os x introduced all of the Unix goodness, which gave you things like GTK, qt, and other X11 stuff....

now apple has killed most of carbon and the java bridge (you still have native java, like swing)

so you really mostly have objective-C for the UI, for the model layer and guts you can use pretty much whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want to upload your app to the App Store it will have to be in Objective-C.